# how to get values from sqlite in view holder

Tags: java, android

product Adapter

```
        public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>{

            private Context context;
            private List<Product> listProducts;

            private SqliteDatabase mDatabase;

            public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> listProducts) {
                this.context = context;
                this.listProducts = listProducts;
                mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(context);
            }

            @Override
            public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_list_layout, parent, false);
                return new ProductViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
                final Product singleProduct = listProducts.get(position);
                  holder.name.setText(singleProduct.getName());

               // holder.quantity.setText(singleProduct.getQuantity());
               //when i call quantity(the ABOVE value) the application crashes and when i call only name the field the values gets displayed 

                holder.editProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        editTaskDialog(singleProduct);
                    }
                });

                holder.deleteProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       mDatabase.deleteProduct(singleProduct.getId());
                       ((Activity)context).finish();
                        context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return listProducts.size();
            }

            private void editTaskDialog(final Product product){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_product_layout, null);
                final EditText nameField = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
                final EditText quantityField = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.enter_quantity);

                if(product != null){
                    nameField.setText(product.getName());
                    quantityField.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQuantity()));
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Edit product");
                builder.setView(subView);
                builder.create();
                builder.setPositiveButton("EDIT PRODUCT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
                        final String quantityStr = quantityField.getText().toString();

                        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(quantityStr))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong. Check your input values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityStr);

                            if(quantity<=0)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"input is less than or equal to zero",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else {

                                mDatabase.updateProduct(new Product(product.getId(), name, quantity));
                                //refresh the activity
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                                context.startActivity(((Activity)context).getIntent());
                            }
                       }
                     }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Task cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }
```

product viewHolder

```
        public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView name;
            public TextView quantity;
            public ImageView deleteProduct;
            public  ImageView editProduct;

            public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                deleteProduct = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_product);
                editProduct = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_product);
                quantity=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name2);
            }
        }
```

Now the issue here is when is use `holder.quantity.setText(singleProduct.getQuantity())` the application crashes.

I also wanted to add date picker dialog and want to display it in the recycler view so for date the code is same like `holder.object.setText` or something else and can we use a form for alert dialog like

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // before
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_dark);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

I have created the database file but the issue is mainly related to recycler view contents and if i wanted multiple holder is it possible to get the contents?

Comment: Your code is ***huge***! Please make sure that your example is [complete, **yet minimal**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: each and every thing is related thats y i have uploaded entire code :)

Comment: Ok, fine then. Did you make sure your code is reproducible? ie, only given your question, someone can reproduce the issue you're facing?

Comment: might be  i haven't thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getQuantity()` returns a `int`. So, Android is trying to search for a resource with `id == getQuantity()` leading to the crash (since you probably any resource with that `id`.

In other words, you are invoking `TextView.setText(int resourceId)` and not `TextView.setText(String text)`).

To fix, change this:

```
holder.quantity.setText(singleProduct.getQuantity());
```

To this:

```
holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(singleProduct.getQuantity()));
```

Comment: hi if i want the date from database then